# Trying to import android lib project from git hub I get Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found. (pics included)

Tags: android, git, android-afilechooser

Hi i am trying to import this 
https://github.com/jfmdev/afiledialog
or
https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser

I get the same message despite which one i try to import... you can see they are both in the lib though.  right now my gradles are only trying to import afiledialog(lib1)  I figured this was better because it has its own gradles and aFileChooser did not(and explanation on how to do aFileChooser would behelpful too)

my apps low-level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ianz.onionmusic"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile project(':lib:lib1')
```

}

top level settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':lib:lib1'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the top-level settings.gradle

```
include ':lib1', 'app'
project(':lib1').projectDir = new File('lib/lib1')
```

Your app settings.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':lib1')    
}
```